# Best way to pull the row that corresponds to a max or min

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have `TableA` and `TableB` that do not have a relationship.

On `TableA` I create a calculated column that computes a minimal value according to a complex expression involving multiple columns from both tables (e.g. see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757321/power-bi-find-closest-location-based-on-lat-lng/50764218#50764218)).

```
MinValue = MINX(TableA, [ComplexExpression])
```

This works fine, but what I'm really looking for is the `ID` for the row where that minimum occurred.

---

For the sake of a concrete example, let's look at the following:

`TableA`:

```
ID   X     Y
-------------
1   2.1  -1.3
2   3.5   0.5
3   6.5   5.9
4   3.1   4.2
5   2.8  -2.7
6   5.7  -1.5
```

`TableB`:

```
ID   X     Y
-------------
A   2.3   2.7
B   2.8  -4.8
C   4.1   1.1
D  -0.5   0.9
E  -3.7   2.4
```

I've added a calculated column to `TableA` that gives the minimal Euclidean distance.

```
MinDist = MINX(TableB, ROUND(SQRT((TableA[X]-TableB[X])^2 + (TableA[Y]-TableB[Y])^2), 2))
```

Now, I'd like to find the `ID` from `TableB` that corresponds to the nearest point. That is, I want the following table:

```
ID   X     Y   MinDist  B-ID
-----------------------------
1   2.1  -1.3   3.12     C
2   3.5   0.5   0.85     C
3   6.5   5.9   5.28     A
4   3.1   4.2   1.70     A
5   2.8  -2.7   2.10     B
6   5.7  -1.5   3.05     C
```

I've gotten it to work with the following

```
MinDist = CALCULATE(MAX(TableB[ID]),
              FILTER(TableB,
                  ROUND(SQRT((TableA[X]-TableB[X])^2 + (TableA[Y]-TableB[Y])^2), 2)
                  = TableA[MinDist]))
```

but I'd ideally like a more elegant/efficient method where I don't have to use the same complex expression twice.

Comment: Well, if you don't know the answers, who does then, Marco and Alberto?

Comment: Related idea: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18476596-custom-reusable-dax-function

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are using your data, this could give you what you need.

Basically, create a measure that acts as a saved function and then call that measure from other measure/column formulas.

So first, I created a measure to calculate the minimum distance.

```
MinDistToB = 
VAR SelectedX = SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[X])
VAR SelectedY = SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[Y])
RETURN
    MINX(TableB, ROUND(SQRT((SelectedX - [X]) ^ 2 + (SelectedY - [Y]) ^ 2), 2))
```

Then I created a measure to get the ID.

```
MinDistToB_ID = 
VAR MinDist = [MinDistToB]
RETURN
    MAXX(FILTER(TableB, [MinDistToB] = MinDist), [ID])
```

Throwing it all in a matrix, I get this.

[image: Using Measures]

If you need them to be columns, you can define the distance as this.

```
Col_MinDist = [MinDistToB]
```

And the ID column as this.

```
Col_MinDistID = MAXX(FILTER(TableB, [MinDistToB] = [Col_MinDist]), [ID])
```

Putting those into a table, I get this.

[image: Using Columns]

With all of this, you can edit the one measure and everything else will get updated accordingly (even the columns).