# Return top value ordered by another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
TableA =
DATATABLE (
    "Year", INTEGER,
    "Group", STRING,
    "Value", DOUBLE,
    {
        { 2015, "A", 2 },
        { 2015, "B", 8 },
        { 2016, "A", 9 },
        { 2016, "B", 3 },
        { 2016, "C", 7 },
        { 2017, "B", 5 },
        { 2018, "B", 6 },
        { 2018, "D", 7 }
    }
)
```

I want a measure that returns the top `Group` based on its `Value` that work inside or outside a `Year` filter context. That is, it can be used in a matrix visual like this (including the Total row):

[image: Matrix Visual]

It's not hard to find the maximal value using DAX:

```
MaxValue = MAX(TableA[Value])
```

or

```
MaxValue = MAXX(TableA, TableA[Value])
```

But what is the best way to look up the `Group` that corresponds to that value?

I've tried this:

```
Top Group = LOOKUPVALUE(TableA[Group],
                TableA[Year], MAX(TableA[Year]),
                TableA[Value], MAX(TableA[Value]))
```

However, this doesn't work for the Total row and I'd rather not have to use the `Year` in the measure if possible (there are likely other columns to worry about in a real scenario).

---

**Note:** I am providing a couple solutions in the answers below, but I'd love to see any other approaches as well.

Ideally, it would be nice if there were an extra argument in the `MAXX` function that would specify which column to return after finding the maximum, much like the [MAXIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) Excel function has.

Comment: Could you explain what you want your measure to return? Do you want it to return a whole table (not a scalar value) with only the A group (two records) because it is the record of A group that has the highest value of all the records? Or is it a sort of rank that you want to get for each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is by using the latest addition to the DAX family:  Window Functions and in this case we will use the INDEX() function.

```
   CALCULATE ( 
        MAX(TableA[Group] ), 
            INDEX ( 
                1,   
                ORDERBY (TableA[Value] , DESC), 
                 PARTITIONBY ( TableA[Year] )
            ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is through the use of the `TOPN` function.

The `TOPN` function returns entire row(s) instead of a single value. For example, the code

```
TOPN(1, TableA, TableA[Value])
```

returns the top 1 row of `TableA` ordered by `TableA[Value]`. The `Group` value associated with that top `Value` is in the row, but we need to be able to access it. There are a couple of possibilities.

---

Use `MAXX`:

```
Top Group = MAXX(TOPN(1, TableA, TableA[Value]), TableA[Group])
```

This finds the maximum `Group` from the `TOPN` table in the first argument. (There is only one `Group` value, but this allows us to covert a table into a single value.)

---

Use `SELECTCOLUMNS`:

```
Top Group = SELECTCOLUMNS(TOPN(1, TableA, TableA[Value]), "Group", TableA[Group])
```

This function usually returns a table (with the columns that are specified), but in this case, it is a table with a single row and a single column, which means the DAX interprets it as just a regular value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store the maximum value and use that as a filter condition.

For example,

```
Top Group =
VAR MaxValue = MAX(TableA[Value])
RETURN MAXX(FILTER(TableA, TableA[Value] = MaxValue), TableA[Group])
```

or similarly,

```
Top Group =
VAR MaxValue = MAX(TableA[Value])
RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(TableA[Group]), TableA[Value] = MaxValue)
```

If there are multiple groups with the same maximum value the measures above will pick the first one alphabetically. If there are multiple and you want to show all of them, you could use a concatenate iterator function:

```
Top Group =
VAR MaxValue = MAX(TableA[Value])
RETURN CONCATENATEX(
           CALCULATETABLE(
               VALUES(TableA[Group]),
               TableA[Value] = MaxValue
           ),
           TableA[Group],
           ", "
       )
```

If you changed the `9` in `TableA` to an `8`, this last measure would return `A, B` rather than `A`.

Comment: thank for all your contributions to PowerBI / DAX on SO. I encountered an error when trying to get a string type associated with a top numeric value. A solution I found used your second solution, but replaced `MAX(TableA[Group])` with `VALUES(TableA[Group])`.