# LOOKUPVALUE based upon aggregate function in DAX

Tags: dax, powerpivot, powerquery, m

I need a calculated column (because this will be used in a slicer) that returns the employee's most recent supervisor.

Data sample (table 'Performance'):

```
EMPLOYEE    |   DATE        |   SUPERVISOR
--------------------------------------------
Jim         |   2018-11-01  |   Bob
Jim         |   2018-11-02  |   Bob
Jim         |   2018-11-03  |   Bill
Mike        |   2018-11-01  |   Steve
Mike        |   2018-11-02  |   Gary
```

Desired Output:

```
EMPLOYEE    |   DATE         |  SUPERVISOR  |   LAST SUPER
---------------------------------------------------------------
Jim         |   2018-11-01   |  Bob         |   Bill
Jim         |   2018-11-02   |  Bob         |   Bill
Jim         |   2018-11-03   |  Bill        |   Bill
Mike        |   2018-11-01   |  Steve       |   Gary
Mike        |   2018-11-02   |  Gary        |   Gary
```

I tried to use

```
LAST SUPER =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    Performance[SUPERVISOR],
    Performance[DATE], MAXX ( Performance, [DATE] )
)
```

but I get the error:

> Calculation error in column 'Performance'[]: A table of multiple
>   values was supplied where a single value was expected.

After doing more research, it appears this approach was doomed from the start. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax), the search value cannot refer to any column in the same table being searched. However, even when I changed the search value to `TODAY()` or a static date as a test, I got the same error about multiple values. `MAXX()` is also returning the maximum date in the entire table, not just for that employee.

I wondered if it was a many to many issue, so I went back into Power Query, duplicated the original query, grouped by EMPLOYEE to get MAX(DATE), matched both fields against the original query to get the SUPERVISOR on MAX(DATE), and can treat this like a regular lookup table. While it does work, unsurprisingly the refresh is markedly slower.

I can't decide if I'm over-complicating, over-simplifying, or just wildly off base with either approach, but I would be grateful for any suggestions.

What I'd like to know is:

1. Is it possible to use a simple function like LOOKUPVALUES() to achieve the desired output?
2. If not, is there a more efficient approach than duplicating the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `LOOKUPVALUE` is giving that particular error is that it's doing a lookup on the whole table, not just the rows associated with that particular employee. So if you have multiple supervisors matching the same maximal date, then you've got a problem.

If you want to use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function for this, I suggest the following:

```
Last Super = 
VAR EmployeeRows =
    FILTER( Performance, Performance[Employee] = EARLIER( Performance[Employee] ) )
VAR MaxDate = MAXX( EmployeeRows, Performance[Date] )
RETURN
LOOKUPVALUE(
    Performance[Supervisor],
    Performance[Date], MaxDate,
    Performance[Employee], Performance[Employee]
)
```

There are two key differences here.

1. I'm taking the maximal date over only the rows for that particular employee (`EmployeeRows`).
2. I'm including `Employee` in the lookup function, so that it
   only matches for the appropriate employee.

---

For other possible solutions, please see this question:

[Return top value ordered by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column)

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple, yet thorough explanation! I got an error the first time I used your code, but I realized it was because the sample data I provided above was overly simplified. When I added another match criteria for an additional field that made it one-to-one, it worked. Thanks again!