# Power BI relativity measure with mutiple groups

Tags: r, powerbi, dax, measure

I have a data that I simply create:

```
Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4    
2014/1/1  A      Y      10  
2014/4/1  A      Y      15  
2015/1/1  A      Z      15   
2015/4/1  A      Z      30  
2014/1/1  B      Y      20  
2014/4/1  B      Y      30   
2015/1/1  B      Z      40   
2015/4/1  B      Z      80
```

I want to create a `measure` in `Power BI` so I can create an interactive visualization. The above data is created for example so we need to suppose that `col2`, `col3` have multiple factors.

The `measure` I want is `relativity`, the value in `Col4` divide the first value under `Col1` and `Col2`.

Result I supposed but I do not need this in data table since when I create the visualization and add the filter for other columns, `Col5`, `Col6`, and etc. that I did not show in this example:

```
Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4   relativity_Col3ALL   relativity_Col3EqualsYorZ
2014/1/1  A      Y      10     1                    1
2014/4/1  A      Y      15     1.5                  1.5
2015/1/1  A      Z      15     1.5                  1
2015/4/1  A      Z      30     3                    2
2014/1/1  B      Y      20     1                    1
2014/4/1  B      Y      30     1.5                  1.5
2015/1/1  B      Z      40     2                    1
2015/4/1  B      Z      80     4                    2
```

So I plot it and add filters beside the plot. When I select Y in the filter `Col3`, the plot will automatically change.

I provide the code I think in `R`:

```
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(dt)
dt[, relativity := Col4 / Col4[1], by = .(Col1, Col2)]
```

But above code is incorrect because it did not consider `Col3`. I just want to mention `Col4 / Col4[1]` or `Col4 / first(Col4)`.

I tried measure in Power BI:

```
relativity = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(dt[Col4], dt[AnotherMeasure]), MIN(dt[Col1]))
```

I know this is false.
Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**
I tried @Alexis Olson's code and modified as:

```
relativity = 
VAR YR = MIN(dt[Col1].[Year])
VAR QT = MIN(dt[Col1].[Quarter])
VAR PF = CALCULATE(TOTALQTD(SUM(dt[Col4]), dt[Col1].[Date]), dt[Col1].[Year] = YR, dt[Col1].[Quarter] = QT) 
RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUM(dt[Col4]), PF)
```

However, when I visualize in the report, it all shows `1`.

I also tried this:

```
relativity = 
VAR YR = CALCULATE(MIN(dt[Col1].[Year]), ALLEXCEPT(dt, dt[Col2]))
VAR QT = CALCULATE(MIN(dt[Col1].[Quarter]), ALLEXCEPT(dt, dt[Col2]))
VAR PFQTD = TOTALQTD(SUM(dt[Col4]), dt[Col1].[Date])
VAR MPFQTD = CALCULATE(MAX(PFQTD), FILTER(dt, dt[Col1].[Year] = YR), FILTER(dt, dt[Col1].[Quarter] = QT)) 
RETURN
    MPFQTD
```

Failed either

Comment: you are providing only `Col4`, then how will it consider `Col3`

Comment: The hard part here is doing the lookup for what to divide by, but this may help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Comment: I mean if there are two factors `Y` and `Z` under `Col3`, relativity will change when I filter them.

Comment: @PeterChen `the value in Col4 divide the first value under Col1 and Col2.`, how do you want to change for 'Col3'  If it is another factor, place it in `by = .(Col1, Col2, Col3)`

Comment: @akrun If I just want to create a table that group by `Col1~Col3`, I can simply do with `by`. However, if the relativity changes once I filter different factors in `Col3`, that way is incorrect

Comment: @akrun I edited my question

Comment: Do you need a function so that subset by the values of 'Col3' and then create the column. like in shiny UI

Comment: @akrun I thought it can be done with `measure` in `Power BI`. As @Alexis Olson mentioned, I think the way is to create another measure to lookup the value of `Col4` in `min(Col1)` first.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I tried to create another measure first, `MinDate_Col4 = CALCULATE(SUM(dt[Col4]), FILTER(ALL(dt), MIN(dt[Col1])))`. It seems incorrect. Do you think I can calculate this based on other columns?

Comment: Do you want `relativity` to be based on the `Col3` value in that row or over all selected `Col3` values?

Comment: I want over all selected Col3. So I can use dynamic table in report. Also, I need `measure` so I can manipulate date hierarchy in report tab and it changes the value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column), you can create a calculated column as follows:

```
relativity =
VAR FirstCol1 = CALCULATE ( MIN ( dt[Col1] ), ALLEXCEPT ( dt, dt[Col2], dt[Col3] ) )
VAR FirstCol4 = CALCULATE ( VALUES ( dt[Col4] ), dt[Col1] = FirstCol1 )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( dt[Col4], FirstCol4 )
```

This looks up the first date when `Col2` and `Col3` are the same value, then finds the `Col4` value on that first date, and finally divides the current `Col4` value by that first `Col4` value.

The `ALLEXCEPT` removes the row context except for the columns you specify. If you want `relativity_Col3_All`, then simply remove that column from the `ALLEXCEPT` specification.

Comment: Could you please explain more on `ALLEXCEPT`?

Comment: Moreover, is it possible to calculate `FirstCol1` when I visualize the in the report. To clarify, it means that if I create a  Table in report, the relativity will automatically change based on what I choose to put in this table, also the date hierarchy. Thank you.

Comment: I searched for the `ALLEXCEPT`, but still get a little bit confused. It seems that when I add `ALLEXCEPT`, I get `relativity_Col3EqualsYorZ`. However, this will not automatically change to get the value of `relativity_Col3_All` once I select all in the report tab and create a table.

Comment: If you are looking for something dynamic, then it cannot be a calculated column, but rather a measure, which needs to be written differently.

Comment: yes. that is what I want to create for dynamic with measure. Does the answer above fit with the measure? I did not get the correct result in the report tab.