# Replacement for MAXX in calculated column when using DirectQuery Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure that retrieves the latest bundle string from a column called Message.

The measure works by getting the first single row from SessionEvents and using MAXX to retrieve the Message from that row.

```
lastBundle = 
VAR SINGLE_ROW = TOPN(1,, FILTER(SessionEvents, SessionEvents[StatusId]=4),
    SessionEvents[DateTime],DESC)

return MAXX(SINGLE_ROW, [Message])
```

I want to use this measure in a calculated column but MAXX is not allowed as a part of a calculated column.

How should i change this calculation to work in a calculated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SELECTCOLUMNS` instead of `MAXX` as explained more fully in this related Q&A:

[Return top value ordered by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column)

```
lastBundle =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER ( SessionEvents, SessionEvents[StatusId] = 4 ),
        SessionEvents[DateTime], DESC
    ),
    "Message", SessionEvents[Message]
)
```

But I don't see any reason why `MAXX` shouldn't work too, except your `TOPN` function has an extra comma.

---

**Edit:** I don't think you can do this at all if you are using a DirectQuery. From [Microsoft's documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about)

> **Limitations in calculated columns:** Calculated columns are limited to being intra-row, as in, they can only refer to values of other columns of the same table, *without the use of any aggregate functions*. [...] Functions that are not supported will not be listed in autocomplete when authoring the DAX for a calculated column, and would result in an error if used.

Comment: My measure works but maxx is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models. As to the double commas, i thought this was required in some functions but it interprets the first comma as a decimal point. I replaced the first comma with a space instead.

Comment: It seems  like SELECTCOLUMNS is not allowed with DirectQuery models either.

Comment: Ah, DirectQuery is much less flexible. Please update your question to include that detail as it is critically relevant.

Comment: Sorry for not having DirectQuery in the question, mixed up PowerQuery and DirectQuery in the summary.