# DAX lookup first non blank value in unrelated table

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

How to lookup the first non blank value in **unrelated** table. I want an equivalent of:

- SQL `outer apply (select top 1 ...)` or
- Excel `VLOOKUP`.

The DAX `LOOKUPVALUE` function as used in that code does not work.

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
      SearchTable[name]
    , SearchTable[id] -- how to get the fist value, if here are multiple id?
    , ThisTable[id]
    )
```

DAX `LOOKUPVALUE` function works fine, if only one unique value is returned as a result. The function `LOOKUPVALUE` returns error  message, if multiple values are found in the search table for one key:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was
>   expected.

[image: error message]
I do not want error message, I am happy with the top 1 result.

Sample data file:

[DAX lookup top 1 value.pbix](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1HdifDXc71GvIXVLCbdlmoycPtu0fxPis&export=download)

### Comment to accepted answer

I favor Alexis Olson's second approach the most, though I prefer `VAR` to `EARLIER` variation:

```
MyLookup = 
var LookupKey = ThisTable[Product]
return
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( SearchTable[Category] ),
    SearchTable[Product] = LookupKey
)
```

I accepted it though I have a strong feeling that this is not the best answer which may exist. The function returns `MAX` instead of `TOP 1` which is obviously additional effort.

The sample data now contains 4 working solutions. I have numbered them according to my preferences. The first two are by Alexis Olson. As far as I could learn from DAX Studio, both solutions are similarly fast and have a simple execution plan. The second solution is the only solution that performs just two table scans (all other approaches have 3 scans). The third solution has a complicated execution plan, and during the third scan it passes through the entire search table, regardless of whether it is a million rows.

This question has a follow up question where I try to compare the queries in Dax Studio:

[How to check in Daxstudio which DAX query has better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59883211/1903793)

### Update seeking further improvements

I wonder if it is possible to achieve a shorter query plan then the current winning answer. The winning code will be evaluated in [DaxStudio](https://daxstudio.org/) and should have shorter query plan then total 20 line of both physical and logical lines of query plan.

```
-- Bounty code
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( ThisTable[Product] ),
    "FilterLookup",
    VAR LookupKey = ThisTable[Product]
    RETURN
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( SearchTable[Category] ), SearchTable[Product] = LookupKey )
)
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, I am cross-referencing here the suggestions I have made [about bounty negotiations in questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931193/filtering-summarizecolumns). The summary points I have made are: (a) bounty negotiating is not of interest to most readers, who do not sign in; (b) on this platform, bounty negotations are sometimes used as a way to obtain free work, and this is normally frowned upon here; (c) once such a bounty has been paid, the outdated offer is rarely removed from where it has been added.

Comment: (I will continue the conversation on the other thread as required).

Comment: Please don’t put meta notices in your question posts. You can use a comment or the bounty notice field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this. Here are the top three that come to mind:

This simplest is a lookup function but only works if there is a single category associated with each product in the `SearchTable`.

```
LookupFunction =
LOOKUPVALUE ( SearchTable[Category], SearchTable[Product], ThisTable[Product] )
```

The following will should still work with multiply categorized products:

```
MaxxLookup =
MAXX (
    FILTER ( SearchTable, SearchTable[Product] = ThisTable[Product] ),
    SearchTable[Category]
)
```

```
CaclculateMaxLookup =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( SearchTable[Category] ),
    SearchTable[Product] = EARLIER ( ThisTable[Product] )
)
```

If you want 2nd or 3rd as a measure instead of a calculated column, they'd need to be adjusted.

---

**Note:** The above work fine as *calculated columns*. If you want them to work as both calculated columns and as measures then adjust them as follows:

```
LookupMeasure =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    SearchTable[Category],
    SearchTable[Product], CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( ThisTable[Product] ) )
)
```

```
MaxxMeasure=
VAR CurrProduct = CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( ThisTable[Product] ) )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( SearchTable, SearchTable[Product] = CurrProduct ),
        SearchTable[Category]
    )
```

```
CaclculateMaxMeasure =
VAR CurrProduct = CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( ThisTable[Product] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( SearchTable[Category] ), SearchTable[Product] = CurrProduct )
```

The difference is that when you're writing a calculated column, there is row context to tell you which product to use. When you write a measure, you need to specify which value from the column `ThisTable[Product]` you intend to use.

Note: If there are multiple products in your filter context and you want the measure to look up the category of the maximal one, then use `MAX` instead of `SELECTEDVALUE`. The latter will return a blank if there are multiple values.

---

**Edit:**

The above formulas worked for the original set of data provided. However, if there are multiple categories associated with a single product in the `SearchTable` then the `LOOKUPVALUE` function will break (since it expects only a single value) and you will need to use one of the `MAX` or `MAXX` versions instead.

Comment: I am surprised that the first solution works with sample data. So far I have been experiencing this behavior: https://radacad.com/find-the-data-value-using-lookupvalue-dax-function-in-power-bi-simple-and-useful (please scroll down to "What if multiple values as the output?" I wonder in what conditions it works.

Comment: I made comment to your answer in my question. Please see update.

Comment: The last one could be rewritten in this way: `CaclculateMaxLookup = 
var LookupKey = ThisTable[Product]
return
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( SearchTable[Category] ),
    SearchTable[Product] = LookupKey
)`

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I am grateful you extended your answer to measures, but all the question is about calculated column. So we have one value of ThisTable in row context. The problem starts when we have two or more different values found in the SearchTable for one key. Please update my sample data or just input two different values in Category field for `apple`. You will not be able to create calculated column using your first approach which is actually the same as the one I used in my question.

Comment: It was obvious mistake in sample data. This solution was banned from the beginning:-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Column =
VAR row_id = ThisTable[id] 
VAR ret_val =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        TOPN (
            1;
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SearchTable;
                SearchTable[id] = row_id;
                SearchTable[name] <> BLANK ()
            )
        );
        "name"; SearchTable[name]
    )
RETURN
    ret_val
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I included your solution in sample data as expected results.

Comment: Do you have any idea how your query could be optimized? The 2nd and 3rd query proposed by Alexis Olson seem to be better in terms of performance as far as I can figure it out from DAX Studio. The drawback of your query is that in the last scan, it scans entire SearchTable (be it a milion rows). Alexis's scans seem to be going only through the number of unique key rows. Also Alexis's query plans are way simpler and shorter. The query plan is bad, but your code delivers fresh idea to cracking problems without MAXX.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this issue:
Measure0 is measure
Measure1 is Calculated Column measure
Apple has no Category because it has 3 categories and can’t pick one, so it returns blank

```
Measure0 =
FIRSTNONBLANK (
    SearchTable[Category],
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( SearchTable[Product] ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( ThisTable[product] ), SearchTable[Product] )
    )
)
```

```
Measure1 =
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK (
        SearchTable[Category],
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( SearchTable[Product] ),
            TREATAS ( VALUES ( ThisTable[product] ), SearchTable[Product] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope you do not mind that I have used daxformatter.com for structuring your DAX code. I will examine performance of your proposal with the benchmark solution.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of the two codes you have proposed?

Comment: Simply, I used CALCULATE to achieve context transition because FIRSTNONBLANK is an iterator, i.e. doesn't understand row context only. TREATAS to achieve a data lineage of the unrelated values. I didn't consider any optimization in those 2 queries but maybe the 2nd one is more optimized (I am not sure).

Comment: These methods have lower performance than the two approaches by Alexis Olsen. However the use of TREATAS might be a hint for improvement of the accepted answer. I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a FIRSTNONBLANK(column, expression) function. Doesn't it help?

Comment: Please see the edit of my question. I uploaded sample data. I would be grateful if you gave it a shot. I think that FIRSTNOBLANK approach needs relationship.