# PowerBI - Lookup by Multiple Criteria

Tags: dax

I'm a new PBI user and would like help on the following:

I have 2 tables (Table 1 & 2). Table 1 is a bookings report showing sales orders, part numbers and order value. Table 2 is a margin report showing sales orders, part numbers with additional descriptive text and margin value.

I would like to copy margin values from Table 2 into a new column in Table 1 by looking up by sales order and part number.

Any help would be appreciated!

Tables[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwyTt.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract text using the [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/left-function-dax) function
2. Use the [COMBINEVALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/combinevalues-function-dax) function to create new column in each table. The new column will merge two existing old columns.
3. Depending if you have unique values in the lookup table, use LOOKUPVALUE function, if not, use this approach: [DAX lookup first non blank value in unrelated table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59310106/1903793)