# Power BI - Getting the most recent value from a related table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know this must be extremely simple, but every example I can find online only works within a single table. I've simplified my situation to these two tables:

[image]

I want to add a calculated column to the first table, showing the most recent value for that id. It also needs to work with text.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the tables?

Comment: Yes, on the id column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this kind of thing [as I've explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column) and all of the solutions there can be adjusted to work in this case.

Doing this as a calculated column and with a second table, you need to make sure you are using row context and filter context appropriately.

Here's are a couple different possibilities I think may work:

```
MostRecentValue =
MAXX ( TOPN ( 1, RELATEDTABLE ( Table2 ), Table2[date] ), Table2[value] )
```

In this one, `RELATEDTABLE` is doing the work of filtering `Table2` to only the rows where `id` matches `Table1`.

```
MostRecentValue =
VAR PrevDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Table2[date] ) )
RETURN CALCULATE ( MAX ( Table2[value] ), Table2[date] = PrevDate )
```

The relationship is more subtle here. Wrapping the `MAX` in `CALCULATE` forces a context transition so that the row context (which includes `id`) is applied to `Table2` as filter context.