# Sum where version is highest by another variable (no max version in the whole data)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling having this measure to work.

I would like to have a measure that will sum the Value only for the max version of each house.

So following this example table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      House_Id       |     Version_Id   |     Value        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |       1000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |       2000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |       3000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1        |       5000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The result of this measure should be: **10.000** because the house_id 1 version 1 is ignored as there's another version higher.

By House_id the result should be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      House_Id       |     Value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       2000       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       3000       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       5000       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

Given the correct answer @RADO gave, now I want to further enhance this measure:

Now, my main Data table in reality has more columns. 
What if I want to add this measure to a table visual that splits the measure by another column from (or related to) the Data table.

For example (simplified data table):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      House_Id       |     Version_Id   |     Color_Id     |       Value      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |    1 (Green)     |       1000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |    2 (Red)       |       2000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |    1 (Green)     |       3000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1        |    1 (Green)     |       5000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

There's a Color_Id in the main table that is connected to a Color table.
Then I add a visual table with ColorName (from the ColorTable) and the measure (ColorId 1 is Green, 2 is Red).

With the given answer the result is wrong when filtered by ColorName. Although the Total row is indeed correct:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ColorName      |      Value       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Green        |       9000       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Red          |       2000       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Total        |       10000      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

This result is wrong per ColorName as 9000 + 2000 is 11000 and not 10000.
The measure should ignore the rows with an old version. In the example before this is the row for House_Id 1 and Color_Id Green because the version is old (there's a newer version for that House_Id).

So:

1. How can I address this situation?
2. What If I want to filter by another column from (or related to) the Data table such as Location_Id? It is posible to define the measure in such a way that could work for any given number splits for columns in the main Data table?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Comment: @AlexisOlson This link refers to the TOP row, but I want the row where version is the maximum version on a group.

Comment: You just need to filter the table you're applying `TOPN` to then.

Comment: But you do need to sum as well as another step, so this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use "Data" as a name of your table.

```
Sum of Latest Values =
VAR Latest_Versions =
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[House_id], "Latest_Version", MAX ( Data[Version_Id] ) )

VAR Latest_Values =
    TREATAS ( Latest_Versions, Data[House_id], Data[Version_Id] )

VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Value] ), Latest_Values )

RETURN Result
```

Measure output:

[image]

How it works:

1. We calculate a virtual table of house_ids and their max versions, and store it in a variable "Latest_Versions"
2. We use the table from the first step to filter data for the latest versions only, and establish proper data lineage
   (https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-data-lineage-in-dax/)
3. We calculate the sum of latest values by filtering data for the latest values only.

You can learn more about this pattern here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/

Comment: now I want to add another column, like Color_Id and separate the latest values by this column in a table. It appears that the total row is ok (only shows the latest value), but each color_id shows the sum of all the versions (not just the latest).

Comment: Where is Color_id column coming from? The same table?

Comment: Yes, same table, but I have the color name in a related table joined by color id

Comment: @janscas - conceptually, you need to add color id to the first two variables, the same way house_id was used. If you need more help to figure this out, it'll be easier to help you if you post it as a new question with a new data sample and desired result.

Comment: ok @RADO, but if I add the Color_Id to the first two variables then the max version will work per House & color and that's not what I want. The max is per House only, but allow me to crossfilter by Color.

Comment: Hey, can you help me out? I feel the answer is simple but i'm unable to achieve it

Comment: I'll be happy to help, but I don't really understand what you are trying to do and what the problem is. It's hard to solve issues like this blindly, without seeing the data /data model and the expected results to test against. Update your question or post a new one with the additional info, and I'll look at it