# DAX Measure to Show Last Status Based on Last Date in a Filter

Tags: sql, powerbi, jira, dax

I pulling data from a Jira database into a Power BI report for Scrum sprint metrics. I'm trying to display the last status an issue was in when the sprint ended. I have two Measures created -- one that shows the last date an issue status was changed in a sprint and another that I want to show what that status was.

```
| Issue_ID |  NEWSTATUS  | CHANGEDATE              | Sprint_Name | Sprint_Start_Date       | Sprint End Date         |
| -------- | ----------- | ----------------------- | ----------- | ----------------------- | ----------------------- |
|  1101    |    Done     | 2020-04-15 08:33:27.547 | SPRINT1     | 2020-04-01 11:16:28.000 | 2020-04-15 08:50:17.000 |
|  1101    | Validation  | 2020-04-15 07:39:48.160 | SPRINT1     | 2020-04-01 11:16:28.000 | 2020-04-15 08:50:17.000 |
|  1101    |    Test     | 2020-04-15 07:26:46.603 | SPRINT1     | 2020-04-01 11:16:28.000 | 2020-04-15 08:50:17.000 |
|  1101    | In Progress | 2020-04-09 10:28:01.217 | SPRINT1     | 2020-04-01 11:16:28.000 | 2020-04-15 08:50:17.000 |
```

The last date measure is working fine. It's showing the last date an issue's status was changed within the time range of the sprint start and end.

```
Status Date =
MAXX (
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER (
            StoriesToSprints,
            StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE] <= StoriesToSprints[Sprint_End_Date]
                && StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE] >= StoriesToSprints[Sprint_Start_Date]
                && StoriesToSprints[FIELD] = "status"
        ),
        StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE], DESC
    ),
    StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE]
)
```

The last status Measure is not working though. It narrows the status down to one record but it's not the last record by date.

```
Last Sprint Status = 
MAXX(
    FILTER (
        StoriesToSprints,
        StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE] = [Status Date]
    ),
    StoriesToSprints[NEWSTATUS]
)
```

I've messed with this Measure for days and can't seem to pull the correct status. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The [Status Date] Measure is returning the latest date, but for some reason [NEWSTATUS] is not returning the associated status from the table. It's returning Validation instead of Done, even though the last status of done is within the Sprint_Start_Date and Sprint_End_Date.

```
| Issue_ID |  Last Sprint Status |       Status Date       |
| -------- | ------------------- | ----------------------- | 
|  1101    |      Validation     | 2020-04-15 08:33:27.547 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the already defined `Status Date` measure in your `Last Sprint Status` measure.

```
Last Sprint Status =
VAR StatusDate = [Status Date]
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            StoriesToSprints,
            StoriesToSprints[CHANGEDATE] = StatusDate
        ),
        StoriesToSprints[NEWSTATUS]
    )
```

For other approaches to this, you may be interested in this post:

[Return top value ordered by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column)

Comment: This didn't work. The status flow (in DESC order) is Done - Validation - Testing - In Progress. The [Status Date] measure is returning the correct date for Done, but in the report the [Last Sprint Status] is returning Validation.

Comment: You're going to need to show an example data table then. I'm shooting in the dark here.

Comment: I've updated the original question with an example of data. There are four rows for the same Jira issue within the Sprint_Start_Date and Sprint_End_Date. The [Last Status] Measure is returning the last date within that time range correctly, but it's not returning the correct [NEWSTATUS] associated with that date.

Comment: Ah, I think the issue is that I forgot about the implicit context transition caused by calling a measure. Calculating `[Status Date]` inside the filter is calculated using the row context as the filter context. You can fix this by storing it as a fixed VAR. See my edit.