# PowerBI/DAX Running total with date comparison between tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a measure to calculate the number of items below the min or above the max stock level.

I have a lot of tables, but the important ones for this issue are:

- **dSAP_MARC**: Center/unit code (Cen.), SKU code (Material), minimum stock level (Estq.seg.), maximum stock level (Estoque máximo) and Inicial date (date from when parameters are valid);
- **fSAP_MB51**: Table with all stock movements, used to calculate daily stock level. Here I have columns Center/unit code (Cen.), SKU code (Material) and moviment date (Dt.lçto);
- **dCalendar**: Calendar table, used for relationships between dates;
- **dSAP_MARA**: SKU table, used for the relationship between SKUs;
- **dCentro**: relationship between Center/unit code.

I need to calculate the stock level status (above max, below min, zero and Ok) for every center, material and date. The desired stock level (from dSAP_MARC) varies over time, and it reflects on the calculated stock level status.

Stock level, calculated from fSAP_MB51:

[image: Sample of table fSAP_MB51]

Stock parameters, from dSAP_MARC:

[image: Sample of table dSAP_MARC]

The desired result of the comparison between tables *fSAP_MB51* and *dSAP_MARC*:

[image: Desired result 1]

How can I do that? I'd tried to do it using virtual tables... But It doesn't work.

Comment: I think a `LOOKUPVALUE` and a `SWITCH` should do the job fine.

Comment: Hi! How can I do that?

Comment: @AlexisOlson, could you help me?

Comment: I'd like to see what code you've tried first. There are lots of very similar questions. I bet you can find some ideas in the questions linked to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column