# DAX - add column with most common value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I have table with following data, columns "Company", "Document", "Link", "Price", "Document Category"

Example:

[image]

I need to add new column (for example Company Category), where will be most accured value of "Document Category" depend on "Company" and with rule, that "Link" column value is not empty.

So the new table would look like this:

- Company A, most common value of "Document Category" (where link is
  not empty) is "Car"
- Company B has "Airplane"
- Company C has "Other"

[image: ry]

It's possible to add new column for this case in Power BI via DAX?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  similar to the [question I linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column). For each `Company`, you want to count how many times each `Document Category` appears and then pick the top one.

```
Company Category =
VAR CurrRowCompany = Table1[Company]
VAR DocumentCategories =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Company] = CurrRowCompany ),
        Table1[Document Category],
        "DocCount", COUNT ( Table1[Document Category] )
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        TOPN ( 1, DocumentCategories, [DocCount] ),
        "Category", Table1[Document Category]
    )
```

Comment: I have the same type of problem but when I implement your answer i get: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: You may have a tie resulting in multiple rows. Try using MAXX instead of SELECTCOLUMNS

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes i think that was the problem. I used the following line of code MAXX(TOPN ( 1, ProductKey, [ProdCount] ),  'FactInternetSales'[ProductKey])