# How to display the most frequent item from another table in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have 2 tables:

- **ProductSales**: each row represents a sold product (ex: ball, chair, glass ...)
- **Regions**: each row represents a geographical region (ex: Europe, America ...) where a product can be sold

These 2 tables are connected to one another by a one to many relationship (1 Region -> * Products) through a column called **RegionId** which indicates where each product in the table **ProductSales** was sold.

My goal is to display in the **Regions** table the name of the most sold product which can be calculated from the **ProductSales** for each region. Would you be able to provide a smart and elegant way to write the correct DAX formula to achieve this task?

I think I need to use the function RELATEDTABLE() function and combine it with some additional function but I had no success thus far.
This is what I tried so far:

```
GROUPBY('ProductSales', 'ProductSales'[RegionId], "Most Frequent Item", 
FIRSTNONBLANK (
    TOPN (
        1, 
        VALUES(ProductSales[ProductKey]), 
        RANKX( ALL( 'ProductSales'[ProductKey]), COUNTROWS(CURRENTGROUP()),,ASC)
    ), 
    1 
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal in 2 steps:

**Step 1**

Add a column in the table **ProductSales** which displays the most frequent item in column **ProductKey** for each **RegionID**:

```
Top Item = 
VAR CurrRowTerritory = 'ProductSales'[RegionId]
VAR ProductKey =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( 'ProductSales', 'ProductSales'[RegionId] = CurrRowTerritory ),
        'ProductSales'[ProductKey],
        "ProdCount", COUNT ( 'ProductSales'[ProductKey] )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX(TOPN ( 1, ProductKey, [ProdCount] ),  'ProductSales'[ProductKey])
```

**Step 2**

Use the RELATEDTABLE() function to import on **Regions** the information just created in **ProductSales**

```
TopItem = MAXX(RELATEDTABLE(FactInternetSales), 'FactInternetSales'[Top Item])
```

Note: my answer was inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796767/dax-add-column-with-most-common-value).

Answer (score 0):

You may not need any `dax` to display `Top sales` for each region, unless there is other restriction that I am unaware:

Suppose this is your original data with 3 type of products `shoe, bag and shirt` being sold in `China, US and Euro` using `region ID`:

[image]

This will be table report **without** any filter by first create relationship for the `Region ID` to display as country:

[image]

By using `Top N filter` in the visualisation, it will be clear that `shoe` is the best sale for each region:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input :) However this is not what I am trying to achieve since I am trying to add a calculated column to the Regions table. However leave your answer anyways because it could be helpful for somebody else!

Comment: Ya, I saw your answer already, it is good also :)