# Lookup tables with no exact match (find first value greater than)

Tags: powerbi, dax, vlookup, lookup-tables

I’m a beginner with DAX and Power BI. I want to know how you would handle problems like this:

I have two tables; Table A with all my objects and characteristics (e.g. construction year or rental income per month). And Table B a “lookup table” where the boundaries for that class are.

Based on my characteristics, I want to bin/class the building in a calculated column (“Rental class”). So if the rental income is €423 it's under class 1 and if the rental income is €608 it's under class 4

Table A

```
Building    Construction_year    Rental_income
B1           2016                 €423
B2           1995                 €650
B3           1949                 €720
```

Table B

```
Rental_class   Rental_boundary
Under_class_1   €424
Under_class_2   €607
Under_class_3   €651
Under_class_4   €720
```

This would be my expected result

```
Building    Construction_year    Rental_income      Rental_class
B1           2016                 €423              Under_class_1
B2           1995                 €650              Under_class_3
B3           1949                 €720              Under_class_4
```

In Excel, I would use VLOOKUP (TRUE), but in DAX I don’t know how to handle this problem.

This situation happens a lot in my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the first class in Table B with boundary greater than the income in Table A.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column), we can use `TOPN` to find the appropriate boundary and then take the class associated with it.

```
Lookup Rental_class = 
VAR Income = SELECTEDVALUE ( TableA[Rental_income] )
VAR Boundary =
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER ( TableB, TableB[Rental_boundary] >= Income ),
        TableB[Rental_boundary], ASC
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( Boundary, [Rental_class] )
```

Or you can use a couple `CALCULATE` functions.

```
Lookup Rental_class =
VAR Income = SELECTEDVALUE ( TableA[Rental_income] )
VAR Boundary =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( TableB[Rental_boundary] ), TableB[Rental_boundary] >= Income )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( TableB[Rental_class] ),
        TableB[Rental_boundary] = Boundary
    )
```

Note: If you want to use these for a calculated column, then remove the `SELECTEDVALUE` wrapper around `TableA[Income]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried both options and they work fine. Thanks