# Dax Formula to filter out Previous records and only keep last transaction of the material number

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of material in which I need to define the last costing of the item over time. I need the table to filter all the old records per material number. I have tried to find the max date per record, but it's not really what I need.

There is table joins per over three tables, these tables are Average cost Lead-time, items to be cleaned-cat-ver2 and last purchased price.

I have tried
[first attempt](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-find-latest-date-value-in-a-group/td-p/379104#)
[second attempt](http://%20https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Finding-the-most-recent-value/td-p/116838)

thanks in advance

[image: table of data]

[image: Tables used in PowerBI]

[image: Table Joins (material number)]

**Edit
Small example**

table
[image: edit]
I need to return line with latest costing date
[image: return example]

I have tried

```
max Date =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'last Purchased Price'[Document Date].[Date] ),
    FILTER (
        'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2',
        'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number]
            = EARLIER ( 'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number] )
    )
)
```

and

```
Max Date 2 =
VAR currentitem = 'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number]
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'last Purchased Price'[Document Date] ),
            'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number] = currentitem
        ),
         ( 'last Purchased Price'[Document Date] )
    )
```

Comment: provide a SMALL example of your requirement with sample data and expected output and what you tried in the post, not with external links.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Comment: Hi Alexis I have tried your Formula of  Top material Date = 
var maxvalue = MAX('last Purchased Price'[Document Date].[Date])
RETURN CONCATENATEX(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                VALUES('Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number]),
                'last Purchased Price'[Document Date] = maxvalue
            ),
            'Items to be Cleaned-cat-veri 2'[material Number],
            ", "
) - Although I cannot get the to return all max dates per material number, the column is just blank? Any ideas I what I am doing wrong? thanks for the reply BTW