# DAX TOP 1 COUNT of GROUPBY

Tags: sql-server, group-by, powerbi, dax

I want to have a Card in Power BI with the result of the select

```
SELECT TOP 1 [COLUMN] FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [COLUMN]
ORDER BY COUNT([COLUMN]) DESC
```

How can I do something like this in dax?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Check here for more info- [link]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/groupby-function-dax)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Comment: You want to get the most frequent value in [COLLUMN] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

My problem was solved by making a

```
SingleLeads = DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact_ProductRequests[COLUMN])
```

I figure this out after checking that there were repeated values ​​in the column.

It was probably, the desperation that settled in not getting the results I wanted, that made me open this question.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

create in powerbi a new table by dax:

```
Top1 = TopN(1, VALUES(Table__[Column1]), Table__[CountOf], DESC)
```

where

```
CountOf = CountOf = count(Table__[Column1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is equivalent the maximum value of [COLUMN], that can be easily obtained with

```
MAX(Table[COLUMN])
```

another solution is using LASTNONBLANKVALUE

```
LASTNONBLANKVALUE(Table[COLUMN], Table[COLUMN])
```

that returns a scalar, otherwise LASTNONBLANK returns a table of a single row and a single column

```
LASTNONBLANK(Table[COLUMN], Table[COLUMN])
```