# DAX - Find and return the category value with the highest summarized measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

In the following example,

Highest Shipping Unit - should be the "ActualArea" where TotalPS has the maximum value.

This is a summarized table grouped by - Customer_ID, ProductDesignation,Package_CD,ActualArea

[image]

As you can see above I cannot produce the desired results. The DAX for HighestShippingUnit measure is as follows. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
HighestShippingUnit =
VAR tab =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            DeviationReport,
            DeviationReport[CUSTOMER_ID],
            DeviationReport[ProductDesignation],
            DeviationReport[PACKAGE_CD]
        ),
        DeviationReport[ActualArea],
        "GroupTotalPS", SUM ( DeviationReport[TotalPS] )
    )
VAR maxps =
    MAXX ( tab, [GroupTotalPS] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX ( FILTER ( tab, [GroupTotalPS] = maxps ), MAX ( [ActualArea] ) )
    )
```

DeviationReport is the name of my table in the dataset.

Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong in my DAX or how to do it in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377/return-top-value-ordered-by-another-column

Answer (score 1):

You were actually very close with your attempt.

If you change the final line from

```
CALCULATE (
        MAXX ( FILTER ( tab, [GroupTotalPS] = maxps ), MAX ( [ActualArea] ) )
    )
```

to

```
MAXX ( FILTER ( tab, [GroupTotalPS] = maxps ), [ActualArea] )
```

then it should work.

The reason is that using `CALCULATE` re-introduces the `ActualArea` filter context that you removed with `ALLEXCEPT` so that you only see the current `ActualArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alexis Olson. I managed to fix the problem.

The DAX is as follows -

```
HighestShippingUnit =
VAR tab =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            DeviationReport,
            DeviationReport[CUSTOMER_ID],
            DeviationReport[ProductDesignation],
            DeviationReport[PACKAGE_CD]

        ),
        DeviationReport[CUSTOMER_ID],
        DeviationReport[ProductDesignation],
        DeviationReport[PACKAGE_CD],
        DeviationReport[ActualArea],
        "GroupTotalPS", SUM ( DeviationReport[TotalPS] )
    )

RETURN
   MAXX(TOPN(1, tab, [GroupTotalPS]), [ActualArea])
    )
```