# Trying to create a Measure to provide the modal result based on row context and column

Tags: powerbi, dax

my data looks like this:

| Date | Region | Country | Area Of Concern | Composite Risk Entry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/23/87 | LAT | Haiti | Operations | High |
| 10/23/87 | LAT | Angola | HR | Medium |

What I am trying to do is construct a measure such that I can have the modal Composite Risk Entry or modal Region within the row and columns context of matrices and other visuals that I might create. Two examples of Matrices I would like to create are as follows:

| Rows and Sub-row | Modal Risk Entry Q1 | Modal Risk Entry Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region ->Area of Concern |  |  |

| Rows and Sub-row | Modal Region Q1 | Modal Region Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Area of Concern -> risk entry |  |  |

Is what I would want to do possible? Is so and you have a solution, would you mind also explaining to me the logic of it as well. I am still learning DAX and the logic of how some of the formulas works escapes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/) suggests the following to calculate the mode of the column `Data[Value]`.

```
Mode :=
MINX (
    TOPN (
        1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Data[Value] ),
            "Frequency", CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Data[Value] ) )
        ),
        [Frequency],
        0
    ),
    Data[Value]
)
```

This returns the value which has the top frequency, which is one particular application of [returning the top value ordered by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377) (which can be done in many ways).

For your particular situation, instead of `Data[Value]`, you'd use the name of the column you want to find the mode of (e.g. `Table1[Region]`).

---

To understand the measure, read from the inside out.

- `VALUES ( Table1[Region] )` is the list of distinct regions within the local filter context.
- For each region, we add the `Frequency` as a new column defined by counting the rows associated with that region within the local filter context.
- Now we have a table with two columns (`Region` and `Frequency`) and take the Top 1 row after sorting by `Frequency`.
- Finally, we take `MINX` (`MAXX` would work too) on this single row (which has two columns) with `Table1[Region]` as the second argument specifying which column to return the min (or max) of.

Comment: Thank you Alexis, this answers my question perfectly.