# Return the largest category as an extra column or measure in DAX based on calculation and with criteria

Tags: dax

I'm a DAX beginner using it in the context of a data model in Excel. I have a large dataset with several tens of thousands of rows split into various groups with record numbers, classes, year, Group name, location, status and lots of other categories of data.

I'd like to add some specific calculated columns for particular key filters such as the location with the largest sales within each Group where the source is still live, and have a measure that works for whichever fields I bring into a pivot (e.g. if I added year, source, state or any combination etc)

For example in the simplified table below I'd like to calculate a column that returns the dominant location for each Group by Sales, subject to only including live records. So for Group A I'd add up all sales for USA and Canada where the Status is live, then take whichever category is largest (Canada for Group A, USA for Group B) and add it as the Dominant location as below:

| Group | Location | Status | Sales | Dominant Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | USA | Live | 500 | Canada |
| Group A | USA | Disc | 250 | Canada |
| Group A | USA | Disc | 290 | Canada |
| Group A | Canada | Live | 875 | Canada |
| Group A | Canada | Live | 115 | Canada |
| Group A | USA | Live | 310 | Canada |
| Group B | USA | Live | 310 | USA |
| Group B | UK | Live | 285 | USA |
| Group B | UK | Live | 705 | USA |
| Group B | USA | Live | 430 | USA |
| Group B | USA | Live | 670 | USA |

My original thought process was to use GroupBy to return a table of live sales by location for each group and then use topn to select the largest location by live sales and then SelectColumns to return the location although this doesn't appear to work (or is coded wrongly). Example failed attempt below:

```
=SELECTCOLUMNS( TOPN(1, GROUPBY('Table',[Location],"Live Sales",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Sales]* IF([Status]="Live",1,0)) ),[Live GNWP]) ,"Location",[Live GNWP] )
```

I have managed to add this column with an intermediate calculated column using:

```
Intermediate=CALCULATE(SUM([Sales]), FILTER('Table', EARLIER([Group]) = [Group] && [Status]="Live" && EARLIER([Location] = [Location])))
```

Then

```
=CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK (
        TOPN ( 1,
            VALUES ('Table'[Location] ),
            CALCULATE ( MAX ( [Intermediate]) )
        ), 0 ),  ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table','Table'[Group] ) )
```

This does work as a calculated column, but my actual data is too large in row count and field count to be adding extra intermediate calculated fields every time I want a new criteria for selecting the largest category. I also cannot replicate this as a measure so would appreciate understanding why my initial method didn't work and if it's possible to generate this field as a calculated column in one step and then additionally how to get it to work as a measure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to write a corresponding measure without intermediate calculated columns:

```
Dominant Location = 
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Group] ), 'Table'[Status] = "Live" ),
        'Table'[Location],
        "@SumSales", SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] )
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        TOPN ( 1, Summary, [@SumSales], DESC ),
        "Location", 'Table'[Location]
    )
```

[image: Power BI Table Visual]

Comment: Thanks, that does it! One point just for people using it is that it throws an error where I include groups where the group has no live business records - though it works perfectly once I wrapped the return part in IFERROR

Comment: This works well, though having rolled this out then there are a couple of extra error catching that I need which is where there is an exact tie between two categories the approach errors out. Equally is it possible to make it so that it dynamically returns the dominant Location subject to any filters applied - e.g. I have a year and a Group type field which would be useful to add in without building specific fields for each combination

Comment: 1. Try using the MAXX approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377) instead of SELECTCOLUMNS. 2. This is possible using the ALLSELECTED function but the specifics are slightly beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: Thanks, using MAXX has solved the issue I was dealing with.