# Return the largest category as a measure in DAX based dynamic filtering criteria

Tags: dax

I'd like to build a measure in DAX to return the largest category (calculated from the data) using a criteria which responds to filters in a report. The data I have is taken from a Power Query and I'm doing this in Excel rather than Power BI directly.

The data below is an example of what I'm trying to do. Using this data I'd like to return which location has the largest sales for *any* combination of filters applied to that data. Filtering for just Entity A the measure should return "Canada" because total Entity A Sales for Canada are 673+280=953 vs 196+715=911 for the USA but filtering for both Entity A and 2021 should return "USA" because the sum of Sales for the USA relating to Entity A in 2021 are 715 vs 280 for Canada.

| Location | Entity | Year | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | A | 2020 | 196 |
| USA | A | 2021 | 715 |
| USA | B | 2020 | 932 |
| USA | B | 2021 | 868 |
| Canada | A | 2020 | 673 |
| Canada | A | 2021 | 280 |
| Canada | B | 2020 | 772 |
| Canada | B | 2021 | 830 |

This is a follow up to this question ([Return the largest category as an extra column or measure in DAX based on calculation and with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673709/return-the-largest-category-as-an-extra-column-or-measure-in-dax-based-on-calcul/67674895?noredirect=1#comment119622005_67674895)) which has a good answer already provided and works for specific supplied criteria. However I have in my actual data approximately 20 fields I'd like to return the largest location for (and other categories) and building separate measures for every combination would be too time consuming.

Comment: Are you wanting to hold any columns constant (like `Group` in the linked post) or do you only expect a single answer for all of the filtered rows?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in having something that responds to any filtered dimension, although I would appreciate being able to hold one column constant e.g. the "live" requirement from the previous example as an additional criteria so in a table I can show the totals for the filtered criteria alongside those for "live" records only.

Answer (score 0):

The basic function for making it dynamic like this is to use [ALLSELECTED](https://dax.guide/allselected/). This is a function with [complex behavior](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/) but not too difficult to work with if you avoid using it inside of an iterator.

```
Top Location = 
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ),
        Table1[Location],
        "@SumSales", SUM ( Table1[Sales] )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( TOPN ( 1, Summary, [@SumSales], DESC ), Table1[Location] )
```

You can still apply non-slicer filters to the table. E.g. instead of `ALLSELECTED ( Table1 )`, write

```
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ), Table1[Status] = "Live" )
```