# Power BI - DAX - table variable - use column for further computation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I am using DAX language in Power BI Desktop.

I have a tricky situation where I am trying to use the column name generated from a table variable.

Table 1: SourceTable

[image]

Table 2: ReferenceTable

[image]

I need to develop a calculated column in SourceTable called EmploymentStatus, based on the corresponding column in ReferenceTable. But I need only the EmploymentStatus value from ReferenceTable, for the maximum InternalID for a given EmployeeEmail.

For example, for the email xyz.gmail.com in SourceTable, I need the EmploymentStatus (calculated column) as 'Active' from ReferenceTable, since 'Active' has the **maximum** of the two available InternalID values (17, 15).

I tried the following code (Calculated Column in SourceTable):

```
EmploymentStatus_SourceTable_CalculatedColumn =
VAR tabl1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ReferenceTable,
        ReferenceTable[EmployeeEmail],
        "MaxInteralID", MAX ( ReferenceTable[InternalID] )
    )
VAR tabl2 =
    FILTER (
        ReferenceTable,
        ReferenceTable[InternalID] IN VALUES ( tabl1[MaxInteralID] )
    )
VAR NewCol =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        tabl2[EmploymentStatus],
        tabl2[EmployeeEmail], SourceTable[EmployeeEmail]
    )
RETURN
    NewCol
```

I realize that I cannot use the column generated from the table variable.

For example, **tabl1[MaxInteralID], tabl2[EmployeeStatus], tabl2[EmployeeEmail]** - are all invalid.

Any idea on how to handle this? You can even provide me with a solution that does not use variables at all. Am okay with any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377), you can find the maximal ID for each email and look up the status for that ID.

Table and column names shortened for readability:

```
CalcCol =
VAR Email = Source[Email]
VAR MaxID = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Ref[ID] ), Ref[Email] = Email )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Ref[Status], Ref[Email], Email, Ref[ID], MaxID )
```

Comment: thanks very much, will get back shortly. appreciate your help

Comment: EmploymentStatus_SourceTable_CalculatedColumn =

VAR Email = SourceTable[EmployeeEmail]

VAR MaxID = CALCULATE ( 
                       MAX(ReferenceTable[InternalID]),
                       ReferenceTable[EmployeeEmail] = Email 
                      )

RETURN

LOOKUPVALUE(
            ReferenceTable[EmploymentStatus],
            ReferenceTable[EmployeeEmail], Email,
            ReferenceTable[InternalID], MaxID
           )

Comment: the above comment has proper table and column names, for anyone who wants to refer later; the solution is what Alexis posted

Comment: EmploymentStatus_SourceTable_CalculatedColumn  = 

var CurrentEmail = SourceTable[EmployeeEmail]

var Status_ =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        topn(1,
            filter(
                ReferenceTable,
                ReferenceTable[EmployeeEmail] = CurrentEmail
            ),
            ReferenceTable[InternalID],
            DESC
        ),
        "@Status",
            ReferenceTable[EmploymentStatus]
    )
return
    Status_

Comment: this code immediately above, is a solution with better performance