# Power BI - Matching closest 3D points from two tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) both containing thousands of three dimensional point coordinates (X, Y, Z), Table 2 also has an attribute column.

Table 1

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6007 | 44268 | 1053 |
| 6020 | 44269 | 1051 |

Table 2

| X | Y | Z | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6011 | 44310 | 1031 | A |
| 6049 | 44271 | 1112 | B |

I need to populate a calculated column in Table 1 with an attribute from Table 2 based on the minimum distance between points in 3D space. Basically, match the points in Table 1 to the closest point in Table 2 and then fetch the attribute from Table 2.

So far I have tried rounding X, Y and Z in both tables, then concatenating the rounded values into a separate column in each table. I then use DAX:

```
CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(Table 2 [Attribute],1),FILTER(ALL(Table2), Table 2[XYZ]=Table 1 [XYZ])).
```

This has given me reasonable success depending on the degree of rounding applied to the coordinates.

Is there a better way to achieve this in Power Bi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757321), except with a simpler distance function. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525377).

Assuming you want the standard [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```
ClosestPointAttribute =
MINX (
    TOPN (
        1,
        Table2,
        ( Table2[X] - Table1[X] ) ^ 2 +
        ( Table2[Y] - Table1[Y] ) ^ 2 +
        ( Table2[Z] - Table1[Z] ) ^ 2,
        ASC
    ),
    Table2[Attribute]
)
```

Note: I've omitted the SQRT from the formula because we don't need the actual distance, just the ordering (and SQRT preserves order since it's a [strictly increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) function). You can include it if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

A function in M Code:

```
(p1 as list, q1 as list)=>

let 
    f = List.Generate(
        ()=> [x = Number.Power(p1{0}-q1{0},2), idx=0],
        each [idx]<List.Count(p1),
        each [x = Number.Power(p1{[idx]+1}-q1{[idx]+1},2), idx=[idx]+1],
        each [x]
    ),
    r = Number.Sqrt(List.Sum(f))

in
    r
```

Each list is a set of coordinates and the function will return the distance between `p` and `q`

The above function (which I named `fnDistance`) can be incorporated into power query code as in this example:

```
let

//Read in both tables and set data types
    Source2 =Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    table2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"X", Int64.Type}, {"Y", Int64.Type}, {"Z", Int64.Type},{"Attribute", Text.Type}}),

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    table1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"X", Int64.Type}, {"Y", Int64.Type}, {"Z", Int64.Type}}),

//calculate distances from Table 1 coordinates to each of the Table 2 coordinates and store in a List
    custom = Table.AddColumn(table1,"Distances", each 
        let 
            t2 = Table.ToRecords(table2),
            X=[X],
            Y=[Y],
            Z=[Z],
            distances = List.Generate(()=>
                [d=fnDistance({X,Y,Z},{t2{0}[X],t2{0}[Y],t2{0}[Z]}),a=t2{0}[Attribute], idx=0],
                each [idx] < List.Count(t2),
                each [d=fnDistance({X,Y,Z},{t2{[idx]+1}[X],t2{[idx]+1}[Y],t2{[idx]+1}[Z]}),a=t2{[idx]+1}[Attribute], idx=[idx]+1],
                each {[d],[a]}),

        //determine set of coordinates with the minimum distance and return associate Attribute
            minDistance = List.Min(List.Alternate(List.Combine(distances),1,1,1)),
            attribute = List.Range(List.Combine(distances), List.PositionOf(List.Combine(distances),minDistance)+1,1){0}
        in 
            attribute, Text.Type)
in
    custom
```

[image]